# Getting the Google Forms edit response URL using getEditResponseUrl() for current submitted form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

So I have this function which is triggered on form submit, and while it populates my entire responses spreadsheet with the form edit URLs , I also want the function to return the URL for just the currently submitted form so it can be used in another function to send an email with the URL in it.  At the moment `resultUrls` is returning the URL for every form response.  How do I grab just the current submissions' URL ?

```
function assignEditUrls() {
  var form = FormApp.openById(formURL);
    //enter form ID here

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses');

    //Change the sheet name as appropriate
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  //var urlCol = 12; // column number where URL's should be populated; A = 1, B = 2 etc
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

    resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  

  return resultUrls;
};
```

Comment: See http://securitasdato.blogspot.com/2014/11/sending-confirmation-emails-from-google.html